# Python and FTPlib Module

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

Recently I have been interested in FTP servers and I was wondering how to get a python script to download and upload files onto a FTP server I have set up. But I can't seem to get it to work. Every time I typ in this like of code:

```
ftp = FTP_TLS("ftp.10.0.1.14")
```

It gives me an error, sorry if it's a stupid question but all my research on the subject say that we're you put the server's adress.

Thanks!

Comment: post the error you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that "`ftp.`" from the beginning of the address you have - it is not part of the IP address. Also, make sure you are importing `FTP_TLS`:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftp = FTP_TLS("10.0.1.14")
```

As a side note, when you are getting an error it is a good idea to include the exact error you are getting in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am new to this whole system!